# Adding figures generated by epslatex terminal of gnuplot into beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, gnuplot, epslatex

I am trying to understand how to add figures generated by using epslatex terminal of gnuplot into beamer presentation. I have the following piece of code for gnuplot:

```
set terminal epslatex size 3.5,2.62
set output 'introduction.tex'
set xlabel '$x$'
set ylabel '$y$'
set format '$%g$'
set xtics ('$-2\pi$' -2*pi,'$-\pi$' -pi,0,'$\pi$' pi,'$2\pi$' 2*pi)
plot sin(x) title '$\sin(x)$' with lines linestyle 1
```

And I have the following .tex file

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\input{introduction}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I am unable to generate any plot into the beamer frames. I am sure I am committing an error. Could you help me understand where. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/TivCS.png Is your tex distribution new enough that it will automatically convert the eps to pdf?